# Adding query functions to the end of conditional torow formulas

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here is my google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rzdjcbVHoTIrlj0b5gT9QFJ294IPJcfNqZG9oTwMiWY/edit?usp=sharing

My goal is to combine the two formulas:

1:

```
=TOROW(MAP(UNIQUE(C1:C9),LAMBDA(tp, IFNA(FILTER(D1:D9, "L1"=A1:A9, "XD"=B1:B9, tp=C1:C9) &"Text"))))
```

Which selects from these columns:

```
| A   | B  | C   | D  |
|---------------------|
| L1  | XD | TP1 | q1 |
| L1  | TT | TP1 | q2 |
| L1  | ss | TP1 | q3 |
| L1  | LL | TP2 | q4 |
| L1  | TT | TP2 | q5 |
| L1  | DD | TP2 | q6 |
| L1  | XD | TP3 | q7 |
| L1  | TT | TP3 | q8 |
| L1  | ss | TP3 | q9 |
```

2:

```
=IF(QUERY(H1:I6, "SELECT I WHERE H='Correct Answer'", 0) = QUERY(H1:I6, "SELECT I WHERE H='Option1'", 0), "AG02", "") & IF(QUERY(H1:I6, "SELECT I WHERE H='Correct Answer'", 0) = QUERY(H1:I6, "SELECT I WHERE H='Option2'", 0), "AG03", "") & IF(QUERY(H1:I6, "SELECT I WHERE H='Correct Answer'", 0) = QUERY(H1:I6, "SELECT I WHERE H='Option3'", 0), "AG04", "")
```

Which selects from these columns:

```
| H               | I        | J          |
|-----------------|----------|------------|
| Correct         | Ah yes   | Nice!      |
| Incorrect       | My My    | not quite  |
| Option1         | A        | A          |
| Option2         | B        | B          |
| Option3         | C        | C          |
| Correct Answer  | A        | B          |
```

So that "Text" is replaced by the second formula.
They can be combined with like:

```
=TOROW(MAP(UNIQUE(C1:C9),LAMBDA(tp, IFNA(FILTER(D1:D9, "L1"=A1:A9, "XD"=B1:B9, tp=C1:C9) &IF(QUERY(H1:I6, "SELECT I WHERE H='Correct Answer'", 0) = QUERY(H1:I6, "SELECT I WHERE H='Option1'", 0), "AG02", "") & IF(QUERY(H1:I6, "SELECT I WHERE H='Correct Answer'", 0) = QUERY(H1:I6, "SELECT I WHERE H='Option2'", 0), "AG03", "") & IF(QUERY(H1:I6, "SELECT I WHERE H='Correct Answer'", 0) = QUERY(H1:I6, "SELECT I WHERE H='Option3'", 0), "AG04", "")))))
```

But the query does not automatically change from I -> J -> K, etc.

Current outcome: E1: q1AG02 then G1: q1AG02

Expected outcome: E1: q1AG02 then G1: q1AG0**3**

Comment: The details of scenario, and data should be included in the body of the question. The question should also provide an example of an expected outcome. Please do NOT assume that users can/will/should open your spreadsheet to understand you question.

Comment: Then place the query formula in replace of text `=TOROW(MAP(UNIQUE(C1:C9),LAMBDA(tp, IFNA(FILTER(D1:D9, "L1"=A1:A9, "XD"=B1:B9, tp=C1:C9) & IF(QUERY(H1:I6, "SELECT I WHERE H='Correct Answer'", 0) = QUERY(H1:I6, "SELECT I WHERE H='Option1'", 0), "AG02", "") & IF(QUERY(H1:I6, "SELECT I WHERE H='Correct Answer'", 0) = QUERY(H1:I6, "SELECT I WHERE H='Option2'", 0), "AG03", "") & IF(QUERY(H1:I6, "SELECT I WHERE H='Correct Answer'", 0) = QUERY(H1:I6, "SELECT I WHERE H='Option3'", 0), "AG04", "")))))`.

Comment: Can you provide the backend logic on how you arrived at the expected outcome you provided. Your first formula gives out output in 3 cells `q1`,`<blank_cell>`,`q7`. your second formula provides `AG02`(if H,I compared) and `AG03`(if H,J compared)... Whats the basis for final merge?!

Comment: Yes, the query section of the combined formula should automatically shift to the next column for after each non-blank display. Therefore, if H,I compared for q1, then if H,J compared for q7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Here's one approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rzdjcbVHoTIrlj0b5gT9QFJ294IPJcfNqZG9oTwMiWY/edit#gid=9881198) you may test out:*

```js
=let(Λ,map(unique(tocol(C:C,1)),lambda(Σ,ifna(filter(D:D,A:A="L1",B:B="XD",C:C=Σ)))),
    torow(map(Λ,scan(,Λ,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,a+1))),lambda(Σ,Δ,if(Σ="",,Σ&switch(ifna(filter(H3:H5,choosecols(I3:5,Δ)=choosecols(I6:6,Δ),choosecols(I3:5,Δ)<>"")),"Option1","AG02","Option2","AG03","Option3","AG04",))))))
```

***scenario1***: *When `TP1` and `TP3` has output values & `TP2` is blank*

[image]

***scenario2***: *When `TP1` `TP2` `TP3` all has output values*

[image]